# Forcing Errors For Unstubbed Routes With Cypress

Tags: testing, server, xmlhttprequest, cypress, stubbing

I am testing a Gatsby app/site with Cypress. It makes a number of calls to an api from a variety of pages. We have taken the decision to stub and mock all these requests, so our tests should never hit our live api.

I was looking for a way to have Cypress error if a request to any of our API endpoints was made that wasn't stubbed, and I found the `force404` config param ([docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Send-404s-on-unmatched-requests)) for `cy.server` which enforces a 404 to be returned for any routes that aren't stubbed. This works well, but actually too well. Gatsby uses XHRs internally to preload other pages (amongst other things) and this causes all those to return 404s as well, effectively breaking the app.

Is there a way to configure `cy.server` to only return 404s from routes that aren't stubbed that are on a particular domain. For example if our api domain is `api.example.com`. Is there a way to configure `cy.server` to return a 404 only for requests to `api.example.com` that are not stubbed, while leaving requests to other domains, or the same domain untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try whitelisting? You could add a rule here to whiletlist all domains that are not your server's

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Change-the-default-whitelisting

```js
cy.server({
  whitelist: (xhr) => {
    // specify your own function that should return
    // truthy if you want this xhr to be ignored,
    // not logged, and not stubbed.
  }
})
```